# Using Swift, how do I call a function coded in one view controller from a button in another view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I've started to learn programming by doing some online courses on the Swift programming language. I'm experimenting with an Xcode project in which I have two view controllers in my main storyboard.

In the project I have a button that takes me from view controller 1 to view controller 2. View controller 2 has three buttons:

- one triggers a new email via the mail app
- one closes the screen and returns the user to the first view controller screen
- and the third one was supposed to call a function (the code for which sits within the ViewController.swift for the first view controller).

The function in question is actually very simple:

```
func ResetGame()
{
    PlaySoundButton()
    score = 0
    totalquestionsasked = 0

}
```

I've lost count of all the ways I've tried to get this to work, but originally I thought it would just be a straightforward button with one of the following snippets of code in the 2nd view:

```
@IBAction func buttonResetGame(sender: UIButton) {

    ResetGame()
}
```

Or

```
 @IBAction func buttonResetGame(sender: AnyObject) {

        ResetGame()
    }
```

But of course this results in a *Use of unresolved identifier 'ResetGame'* error.

I also tried coding the function directly within the button code as per the following example:

```
@IBAction func buttonResetGame(sender: UIButton) {

    PlaySoundButton()
    score = 0
    totalquestionsasked = 0

}
```

But of course that didn't work either.

I've researched this and it appears this is possible in Objective C and other programming languages, but I can't seem to find examples of this using Swift. Does this mean it's not possible, or just that it's not the done thing?

In summary:

- Is this possible?
- If so, how?
- If it's not recommended, why not?
- And finally, what's the recommended approach to use a function across view controllers?

Comment: Can you post some code? Especially the function in question. Then we can advice on the best possible solution.

Comment: @RMenke No worries, just edited the question to include the code. As you can see, the function is very simple.

Comment: Google singleton and delegation. This question has been asked many times before and there are excellent answers in swift.

Comment: @RMenke Ok, great! Thank you!

Comment: @Lubos In one of my online courses I've just discovered UIViews. If I used a UIView in my main view controller to do what I'm currently doing in my second view controller, does that mean that all the coding for my buttons, labels etc located within the UIView would be part of the same view controller? If so, would I be able to call the function from a button in the UIView as opposed to trying to do it from the second view controller? (My second view controller was intended to provide further info/help, the ability to email feedback, and reset the score). Is this a practical solution?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is possible, but not recommended, because a View Controller is there for displaying a view, not for sharing a functionalities across different View Controllers.

You should implement this by creating a separate class to be referenced from the both View Controllers, where you would define this function, which holds the common functionality.

**EDITED**:
If you don't want to share common functionality from 2 view controllers, but you just simply need to call some code from another controller, you can use delegation pattern like

```
class FirstController: UIViewController, YourProtocol {

     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject?) {

         if segue?.identifier == "yourSegueName" {
             let viewController = segue!.destinationViewController as! SecondController
             viewController.controller = self
         }
     }

     func someFunction() {

     }
}

class SecondController: UIViewController {

     var controller: YourProtocol?   // reference to the delegate alias First Controller

         override func viewDidLoad() {
              super.viewDidLoad()
              controller.someFunction()   // call function from the delegate alias first controller
    }

}

protocol YourProtocol {

     func someFunction()

}
```

Comment: Okay, so, I can create my own class and then that would be available across the app regardless of view controllers etc? Is this fairly straightforward to do?

Comment: Yes, sure. You just create a class, you instantiate it in the both controllers and call the function when needed. This is a good practice if the function executes common functionality for both view controllers.

Comment: Ok, great! I keep learning new things! :) I'll see what I can find on how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Hold on a second. What @Monomeeth wants and needs is either `delegation` or a `singleton` Take a look at what his function does. It alters data in the first VC. A separate class of which both VC1 and VC2 have their own instance will not solve his problem.

Comment: @RMenke Ok, so I need to research delegation and singleton to solve this problem, but it's worth learning about creating classes too? But classes are no good for altering data in one view controller from another?

Comment: @Monomeeth classes are language constructs, singletons and delegation are patterns. Things you build by combining classes / protocols / properties / methods,... Classes are in essence just containers.

Comment: @RMenke Wow, that's an easier way to look at it! :) I've signed up for a few "beginners" courses on Swift, but they all assume a degree of knowledge without realising it. All of them throw these terms at you without explaining them. Like, how is someone who is truly a beginner supposed to know what a variable, constant, initialiser, function, method, class, delegation or singleton is (to name a few). LOL I'd be more than happy to pay money for a course that just explains in really simple terms what these things mean (for example, "classes are in essence just containers").

Comment: @RMenke - it's was not so much clear to me what was required. That's why I mentioned "In general" in my answer. Of course, the delegation pattern is there as well. If it's not about sharing common functionalities, then delegation pattern is enough.

Comment: @Lubos I've been working through the delegation pattern you suggested and after some trial and error have got it all setup and coded so that Xcode doesn't indicate any errors. It compiles successfully and runs to the simulator and to a physical device fine, but when I press on my 'Reset' button it just returns me back to the first screen without actually calling the function. That is, I wanted the function to reset the score etc but this doesn't happen. Not sure if this is relevant, but I'm using a Modal segue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To call ResetGame() you need instance of 1st view controller then you can call `instance.ResetGame()`. You can pass the instance of 1st view controller to 2nd View Controller using

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
            destinationVC.instance = self
        }
```

Comment: Wrong direction of passing data ;) But this would create horrible code smell. Don't ever do this. Send data forwards with `prepareForSegue` And create a descent delegation pattern to pass data back.

Comment: @RMenke I am passing of instance of first view controller to second when button on first view controller is clicked so I think direction is correct. Agree that should not pass instance of view controller and descent delegation patter would be better. Didn't include to keep answer simple.

Comment: @2ank3th Ok, so, if I try this do I need to import some sort of framework? I get a _use of undeclared type 'ProductSKUDetailsTableViewController'_ error.

Comment: Updated the answer. Change ProductSKUDetailsTableViewController with name of your second view controller.

Comment: @2ank3th I'm sorry, but I must be missing something obvious. I've tried using the code in either and both view controllers, and I've tried doing things in a different order. I've also removed and re-added the button, and edited the code to alternate the view controller references, but no matter what I do I run into problems. I think the issue is with the .instance bit, but I'm not really sure. Thanks anyway - I appreciate the time.